# sorting of collection does not work

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have encountered a strange behaviour when I try to sort a collection.
When I sort a collection with name "collection_name" by

```
{% assign collection = site.collection_name | sort:"weight" %}
```

there is no problem. All collections are available in `site.collections` and
the same collection can be accessed via

```
{% assign collection_to_be_sorted = site.collections[collection_name].docs}
```

but sorting

```
{% assign collection = collection_to_be_sorted | sort:"weight" %}
```

leads to the error

```
Liquid Exception: undefined method `sort' for nil:NilClass in _includes/navigation.html
```

However, `{{ collection_to_be_sorted.weight }}` exists. Does anyone have an idea why it doesn't work?

This is quite annoying because I want to go through all collections and sort them.

Comment: Remove the `.docs` from the end of your `assign`?

Comment: This does not work. Without `.docs`, I only get the collection properties like label, directory etc. The pages in the collection are in `.docs`. I also compared the outputs of `site.collection_name` and `site.collections[collection_name].docs`, which are the same. However, the latter one cannot be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression `site.collections[collection_name].docs`, `collection_name` is treated like a variable by liquid. So, no collection is returned.

Try to quote it to make it a string :

```
site.collections['collection_name'].docs
```

Comment: This is interesting. If I sort `site.collections['collection_name'].docs`, it works! If I sort `site.collections[page.collection].docs`, I get the error, although the attribute `page.collection` is equal to the string `"collection_name"`. 

The command `{{ site.collections[page.collection].docs }}` shows an output. So, the collection is returned.

Comment: `page` is a reserved hash that contains current page datas. You cannot assign any new variable to it from liquid. And for me `{{ site.collections[page.collection].docs }}` is `nil`.